# Trying to Remove Dupes From a Linked SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a linked server with the code below. However, it is not allowing me because of the this error.

> The object name '[ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[FinalTable]' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Here is my code:

```
insert into [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[tempTable]
SELECT * from [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[FinalTable]

delete T1

from [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[tempTable] T1, [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[FinalTable] T2
where T1.ACCOUNT = T2.ACCOUNT
and T1.ID > T2.ID
TRUNCATE TABLE [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[FinalTable]
INSERT INTO [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[FinalTable] SELECT * FROM [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[tempTable]
DROP TABLE [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[dbo].[tempTable]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the linked server and database listed on too many lines, here is what worked:

```
insert into [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[tempTable]
SELECT * from [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[FinalTable]
delete T1
from [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[tempTable] T1, [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[FinalTable] T2
where T1.PLAYERID = T2.PLAYERID
and T1.id > T2.id
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[FinalTable]
INSERT INTO [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[FinalTable] SELECT * FROM [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[tempTable]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tempTable]
```